# 2 dimensional Dynamic array Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to declare 2 dimensional **Dynamic** array in Kotlin?

I am trying to do it with `ArrayList` but it fails

```
var dynamicarray =ArrayList<Int>(4,{ArrayList<Int>(3)}) //error
```

It works fine for array but not for `ArrayList`

```
var staticarray = Array(4,{IntArray(3)}) // no error
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's an exact duplicate. In this question, the two-dimentional array/list is initialized upon construction, while the linked one is about creating an empty list.